# Creating dynamic ADODB connections in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, adodb

I have a list of Database connection strings, Database Name.  These databases have the same table structure.  What I am trying to do is dynamically create a connection to each one, add/delete/modify a table, however, if an error pops up anywhere, then RollbackTrans, else, CommitTrans.

My basic question to get my on the correct path is this:

Is this code possible in Classic ASP to make Dynamically named connections?

```vb
'create the dynamic object
execute("Set Con" & index & " = Server.CreateObject(""ADODB.connection"")")
'connect to the dynamic object
execute("Con" & index & ".Open " & DBString(index))
```

The error I get is `'Expected end of statement'` on the `.open` line (the last one)

Comment: What's the `DBString()` function doing? It's not a built in function.

Comment: Only the connection string will vary, and its a string so simply reassign the connection objects .ConnectionString propery and disconnect/reconnect as needed or feed it to a function. There is no need to execute/evaluate VBScript in string.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server etc).

Comment: @AlexK. Agreed but it looks like the OP is trying to build multiple dynamically built `ADODB.Connection` objects the question is why? Infact why would you even need to change the Connection String? If they are using SQL Server for example it can use the same connection to enumerate all databases, tables, views you name it.

Comment: DBString() is my connection string (driver, un, pw, db to connect to).
I am connecting to MySQL and SQL Servers.  The DBString() is an array of connection strings.
I have multiple dbs that have the same structure(layout).  When I add a table to one db, I want it to add to all.  If an error occurs anywhere, I want to back out of any changes and report the error.

Comment: I have found by the answer below, it would be easier to make an array of connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick: Just use an array of connection strings. From this you create an array of connections. Then you can iterate over this array and send your commands to the separate databases.

```
  dim connectionStrings(1)
  dim connections(1)
  dim curConn

  connectionStrings(0) = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=.\EXPRESS2012;Database=master;uid=youruser;pwd=yourpwd"
  connectionStrings(1) = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=.\EXPRESS2012;Database=model;uid=youruser;pwd=yourpwd"

  for curConn = 0 to ubound( connectionStrings)
    set connections(curConn) = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connections(curConn).Open connectionStrings(curConn)
  next

  dim cmd : cmd = "select @@servername, db_name()"
  for curConn = 0 to ubound( connectionStrings)
    dim rs
    set rs = connections(curConn).Execute( cmd)
    Response.write( rs( 0) & ":" & rs(1) & "<br />")
    rs.close
    set rs = nothing
  next


  for curConn = 0 to ubound( connectionStrings)
    call connections(curConn).Close
    set connections(curConn) = nothing
  next
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't even think of dumping all of that into an array.  Very nice.

Comment: @EglCode Why is that nice? It will creating overheads by having multiple connections, you can do all that from one connection you don't have to switch the database in the connection string. But since you don't answer questions it's pointless trying to help you.

Comment: @Lankymart, sorry my response time did not fit your expectations, went on vacation for a week.  
If I close the connection then I cannot back out or cancel the transaction.  Lets say on the last connection, I get an error, I want the ability to cancel all of the other changes to the other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql Dynamic Connection String , sample for t=1 to 4 , four different database connection conns(t)

```
dim conns(4)

Set Conns(1)=Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")

Conns(1).Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost;port=3306;DATABASE=dbname;UID=root;PASSWORD=pass;OPTION=3"
Conns(1).Execute "SET NAMES 'latin5'"
Conns(1).Execute "SET CHARACTER SET latin5"
Conns(1).Execute "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'latin5_turkish_ci'"
```